# GnuPG Error - GnuPG failed to start because of "unsafe permissions"

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10, gnupg

Every time I start Kubuntu, I get same error. Here is the KSnapshot:

[image: GnuPG error]

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The error message already includes a detailed problem statement. You probably migrated your `.gnupg` folder from another machine, or tampered another way with the file permissions.

These two lines fix the permissions. The first one ensures that the `~/.gnupg` folder (and everything in it) is actually yours. To possibly overtake ownership, it requires root privileges, thus the `sudo`. The second line makes sure nobody but you can read its contents (remove read, write and execute permissions for group and other users).

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ~/.gnupg
chmod -R go-rwx ~/.gnupg
```